# XNA how to draw some sprites tiled/wrapped and others not?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, spritebatch

I already have:

```
mySpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

and take care to draw all my sprites in order.

I now want to draw some textures tiled. Do I have to create another SpriteBatch and call:

```
mySpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
```

To draw my tiled textures? But won't these tiled sprites be drawn on top the ones already drawn with the previous SpriteBatch?

**What I would really like is to be able to do is draw some sprites normally and some tiled using the same SpriteBatch then my ordering wont be messed up. Is this possible?** I tried:

GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap; 
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;

In my first and only SpriteBatch but got the InvalidOperationException:

> Cannot change read-only SamplerState. State objects become read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change property values, create a new SamplerState instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Here's the problems you are having:**

1. Sorting for sprite batches only applies within that batch. At `End`, everything in the batch gets drawn to screen and becomes pixels. The default depth state for `SpriteBatch` does not read the depth buffer.
2. State objects (eg: `SamplerState`) are read-only once they are used. In this case, you're accessing the state that the graphics device *is currently using*. You can create a new state of your own, if you like - or use different existing ones.

**Here's what you need to do:**

Fortunately you don't have to create a custom `SamplerState`, as you can just use the built-in `SamplerState.LinearWrap`. Pass it into `SpriteBatch.Begin` like so:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
                  null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);
```

(Note the use of `Deferred` - this is the default. You should only use `Immediate` if you actually need that behaviour, as it is much, much slower. Passing `null` in for state objects causes `SpriteBatch` to use the default state object for that state.)

Then it's a simple matter of tiling your sprites. The trick to do this with `SpriteBatch.Draw` is the source rectangle parameter. **You can specify a source rectangle that extends beyond the edge of your texture.** If, for example, you wanted to draw your sprite tiled 3 times horizontally and 2 times vertically, here's how:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, myPosition,
                 new Rectangle(0, 0, myTexture.Width * 3, myTexture.Height * 2),
                 Color.White);
```

Then, to draw a non-tiled sprite, simply don't specify a source rectangle.

---

It is worth noting the reason for the existence of `TextureAddressMode.Clamp`: If you draw a tile with `Wrap`, and then position or scale your sprite it so that a pixel in the sprite's texture does not perfectly line up with a pixel on the screen, you will find that your sprite gets a fringe where blending is happening between two pixels on the opposite sides of the texture. `Clamp` prevents blending from doing this by extending the edge pixels of the texture out to infinity. To avoid this problem you must either have pixel-perfect sprite positioning, or ensure that your art assets look reasonable if it happens.

It's also worth noting that this wrapping technique precludes the use of texture atlases. So, if you have many different tile types, it can be better for performance to just draw the tile multiple times. ([Details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288))

Comment: +1 Really nice answer! I didn't know the part about sorting is only in that batch, never thought of it, but it really makes sense.

Comment: great answer, and thanks for the info on immediate - it was on my todo list to check out other options.

Comment: however I am relying on the TextureAddressMode.Clamp at the moment - I use it to strech my sky texture across the screen. so my question becomes: can I create a custom SamplerState and changed the SamplerState after by SpriteBatch has begun?

Comment: @Fëanor No, you need to end the batch and start a fresh one (you can use the same `SpriteBatch` object) with the desired settings. `SpriteBatch` basically makes a list of sprites internally and then draws the list when you call `End()`, using the states you specified to `Begin`, and batching together as many sprites as possible ([details](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288)). The exception to this is `Immediate` mode, which draws immediately on `Draw()` instead of filling a list. This allows you to set states on the graphics device - but you don't get batching (slow).

Comment: (It's worth pointing out that you can still do stretching with `Wrap` specified. Just specify a scaling factor or a larger destination rectangle, and leave the source rectangle sized "normally". Unless you're actually deliberately rendering outside the clamped region to stretch only the edges of the texture?)

Comment: I can still do streching with a larger destination rectangle - good point!

Comment: why do you say this technique precludes use of sprite sheets? i can have my sprite sheet and get the a particular tile using sourceRectangle then wrap it ... can't I?

Comment: No, because the source rectangle is used for both the wrapping (if you set it beyond the normal bounds of the texture - `Wrap` mode basically creates a virtual texture that repeats forever), and which sprite is selected in the sprite sheet (it's traditional purpose - you set it to a sub-region of the texture to select a sprite). So it's impossible to do both at once.

Comment: ack i thought it was destinationRectangle for wrapping, ok i see your point, cheers